# How do i change the data of my notification to be the data from the comment in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-notification

I have set up notifications so that when a user comments on another users post the owner of the post receives a notification to let them know of the comment.

but at the moment the notification just says displays what is added to the return statement in the following:

```
public function toArray($notifiable) {
    return [
        'data' => 'Test notification'
    ];
}
```

But when a user posts a comment i want to replace the 'Test notification' with the following:

the name of the user that commented on the post saying for example:

```
'John commented on your post'
```

how do i do this so that it always displays the users name of the person thats commented.

if this helps i have passed in the user, comment and post at the top in the construct function like this:

```
public function __construct(User $user, Post $post, Comment $comment) {

    $this->user = $user;
    $this->comment = $comment;
    $this->post = $post;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the `$notifiable` will be the `User`. So you can use it if this is the case with your code.
If not, working with the code you provided you will do something like that

```
public function toArray($notifiable) {
    return [
        'data' => $this->user->username.' commented on your post',
        'email' => $this->user->email
    ];
}
```

You can learn more about the `$notifiable` on the doc here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait

Comment: is there a way to get an email as well for example. 'email' => $this->user->email or can you not do that?

Comment: for sure. You have access to the `User` model

Comment: So if i get an email like above do i use it like this:   {{$notification->email['email']}} or is this wrong?

Answer (score -1):

have a look at this article. it has answers to all of your questions.

[the medium blog answer link](https://medium.com/@alouinimedamin/customize-your-database-notification-and-database-channel-in-laravel-576c8fa5f498)

Comment: don't forget to mark it as correct if it helped you.

Comment: Refrain from giving link only answers, links are not discouraged in answers, however, they should serve to support the answer in itself, not be the answer itself.

Comment: ok, will keep this in mind from now onwards.